# How to compress css files and javascript file in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I want to compress css files and javascript files in my project. Is there any plugin to do that? :">

Answer (score 4):

I used [bundle-fu](http://code.google.com/p/bundle-fu/), worked great.

- compresses both css and javascript
- has no external dependencies
- is around for a long time (proven)
- is simpler to use than Jammit (no config file).
- [more](http://code.google.com/p/bundle-fu/#WHY_BUNDLE-FU_IS_SPECIAL)

[Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) is newer and fancyer.

- it has better compression as it can use the latest compressor from google [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) considered having the best compression
- is harder to use than bundle-fu (makes you define a config file)
- has external dependencies (the java runtime to run the closure or yui compressors, written in java).

Comment: Is there any plugins that I can compress my javascript and css files and then they're upload to S3 automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) for this.

Comment: Another option is [asset_packager](http://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager). I used this over Jammit. Easy to set up, define assets in a yml file, couple of Raks tasks to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1 will do this [automagically](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/automagical), as Ryan Bates shows in his [Rails-3.1 Overview](http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview).